# Class method is accessing instance variable

Tags: ruby

I'd like to understand this code. Why is it returning `Hello` instead of `Howdy!` ?

```
class Speaker
  @message = "Hello!"

  class << self
    @message = "Howdy!"

    def speak
      @message
    end
  end
end

puts Speaker.speak
```

Answer (score 4):

First off, your message `@message` is not an instance variable, or rather not the type of instance variable you may be thinking about: it's a class-level instance var, so an instance variable of `Speaker` itself, which as an object is an instance of class `Class`.

Here's a version of the code that does what you're trying to do with a local variable and a closure:

```
class Speaker
  @message = "Hello!"

  class << self
    message = "Howdy!"
    define_method(:speak) { message }
  end
end

Speaker.speak
#=> "Howdy!"
```

And here's some code that illustrates the difference between the class-level instance variable and a "normal" instance variable:

```
class Speaker
  @message = 'Howdy!'   # class-level instance variable

  def initialize
    @message = 'Hello!' # instance variable of Speaker's instances
  end

  def speak
    @message
  end

  class << self
    def speak
      @message
    end
  end
end

Speaker.speak
#=> "Howdy!"
Speaker.new.speak
#=> "Hello!"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is your code, except I've defined the class method in the usual way (`def self.speak...`). As a class method is nothing more than an instance method defined on the class' singleton class, this change is merely a different way of creating the same class method. (If you doubt that, run the code below both ways.) I made that change because I thought it would make my explanation of what is happening clearer. I also added a `puts` statement.

```
class Speaker
  @message = "Hello!"

  def self.speak
    puts "self=#{self}"
    @message
  end

  class << self
    @message = "Howdy!"
  end
end
```

The first line of the class definition creates a class instance variable `@message`:

```
Speaker.instance_variables
  #=> [:@message]
Speaker.instance_variable_get(:@message)
  #=> "Hello!"
```

By constrast,

```
@message = "Howdy!"
```

creates an instance variable on `Speaker`'s singleton class:

```
Speaker.singleton_class.instance_variables
  #=> [:@message]
Speaker.singleton_class.instance_variable_get(:@message)
  #=> "Howdy!"
```

Now invoke `speak` on `Speaker`:

```
Speaker.speak
  # self=Speaker
  #=> "Hello!"
```

As `self #=> Speaker`, `speak` is obviously returning the value of the class instance variable.

For `speak` to return the value of the instance variable defined on `Speaker`'s singleton class we can write the following:

```
class Speaker
  @message = "Hello!"

  def self.speak
    puts "self=#{self}"
    puts "singleton_class = #{singleton_class}"
    singleton_class.instance_variable_get :@message
  end

  class << self
    @message = "Howdy!"
  end
end

puts Speaker.speak
  # self=Speaker
  # singleton_class = #<Class:Speaker>
  # Howdy!
```

In the last expression, because `self` equals `Speaker` and `self` is the implied receiver when there is no explicit receiver, `"singleton_class` is equivalent to `Speaker.singleton_class`.

Answer (score -1):

The reason this code returns 'Hello' is that it is attempting to change an instance variable in a class << self block.

Class methods are for anything that does not deal with an individual instance of that class - instance variables are tied to individual instances of a class, and we can't change instance variables at a class level.

Instead of using an instance variable in the speak method, we should use a class variable (denoted by @@).

As an example, the following code will return 'Howdy!' -

```
class Speaker
    @@message = "Hello!"

    class << self
        @@message = "Howdy!"

        def speak
           @@message
        end
    end
end

puts Speaker.speak
```

Comment: `@message` above is a class level instance variable, it belongs to the class `Speaker`, which itself as an object is an instance of class `Class`: `Speaker.class #=> Class`, `Speaker.instance_variables #=> [:@message]`